# Add leading Zeros to converted Integer Java

Tags: java, parsing, int, parseint, leading-zero

I get `gpnString` as a `String` and I have to parse it to an `int`.
 I was using `Integer.parseInt(gpnString)` but `gpnString` contains leading zeros and they get removed with `Integer.parseInt()`.

The `gpnString` has allways the length of `8` so I tried to add so many `0` as needed but the int detects it as `NULL` so it does not add the number `0`. This is my Code:

```java
int parseToInt(String gpnString) {
        int gpn = Integer.parseInt(gpnString);
        for (int addZero = 8 - String.valueOf(gpn).length(); addZero != 0; addZero--) {
            gpn = 0 + gpn;
        }
        return gpn;
}

/*
  Input : gpnString = "00012345"
  Output: 12345
*/
```

I have looked this up on Stackoverflow but I only found an answer like this:

```java
String gpn = String.format("%08d" , gpnSring);
```

I have tried it but you get a `String` so I would have to parse it again and this would lead to the exact same Problem as before.

**Edit**:
I heard an `Integer` or `int` can not have leading zeros...
I use the `gpn` for personal identification in a Database. Would the best Idea be to edit the grafical output so it just looks like it has the `0`? Or is there a better way to solve this?

Comment: An integer does not have leading zeroes. The integer value of `01` is `1`. There's no way to store leading zeroes in an `int` or `Integer`.

Comment: Partial aside: if you write an int literal starting with zero, it's actually an octal literal. So `010` is actually equal to 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An integer can't have leading zeros.

As leading zeros add no mathematical significance for an integer, they will not be stored as such. Leading zeros most likely only add to the readability for the human viewing / processing the value. For that usage a string can be used in the way you already found yourself.